# Migration: Office 2003 > 2010 | Windows XP > 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, migration, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-office

My company will be migrating from `Windows XP/MS Office 2003` to `Windows 7/MS Office 2010`.

We will have a set of `Excel` and `Access` files and we should be sure that all works perfectly after the migration.

What I'm looking for, is a knowledge base where I can learn what issues I can encounter and their solutions.

Where can I find this? Of course, I'm expecting answers more precise than "MSDN" or "GOOGLE" ;)

Comment: There really is no answer to this, other than "test it, then test it some more". When you encounter a problem, sites like [su] and Googling around will help.

Answer (score 4):

Well, Microsoft provides some [instructions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/help/upgrading-from-windows-xp-to-windows-7) for transitioning from Windows XP to Windows 7, though they are mostly oriented towards end users.

The best way to learn about the issues that you might encounter during any migration, is to perform it on a sandbox/testing environment and resolve them there, before performing the task on live systems.

When you manage chaos for a living, there aren't any checklists with things that can go wrong. And even if they are, it's almost definite that you may encounter additional problems due to the unique characteristics of your installation.

Answer (score 2):

The website for Microsoft documentation about performing Windows 7 upgrades (videos and whitepapers) is at the springboard site [Windows XP to Windows 7 Migration Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ee150430).  The migration guide for Office 2010 is located in the [Office 2010 Resource Kit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624353.aspx).  I would also note that this late in upgrade cycle you might also consider Office 365 and/or Google Apps to replace Office.

Additionally take a look at the [MAP toolkit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/solutionaccelerators/dd537566) as a means to identify potential issues.

Answer (score 0):

Download the [Microsoft Deployment Toolkit 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/solutionaccelerators/dd407791) and read the documentation that comes with it.  It's very thorough and covers migrations using the MDT alone, Windows Deployment Services, and integration with SCCM.  What you're trying to accomplish is pretty straightforward and MDT should have all of the answers you need and the preparation steps you need to take.

Comment: While MDT makes it pretty easy to deploy, really not sure how it helps to ensure his custom Excel and Access files will work in the new environment.

Comment: That's where the testing comes in.  If there's an issue with compatibility you have to sort that out before you do any migration.